# Dynamic to static internal IP address (Snow Leopard server)

Tags: mac, ip-address

I purchased a new Mac mini server, since my old iMac, which was a server pretty much died.  My problem is this.  How do I change my internal IP address for my mac mini server to a static address, like 192.168.0.2?

Before you guys harp on me, my old server was running Ubuntu Hardy and I only had to map the IP address in the router, which would automatically assign the reserved address through DHCP. Now, I know things are different between the two, but my problem is that the mac is not accepting the assigned IP address or the router just is not assigning.  However, every time I have manually changed it on the Mac to an address of my choice, it takes the computer off the Internet.  My router is a NetGear WTG624 v2, I believe.

I need this to work, so I can utilize Dynamic DNS.

Comment: Should be moved to Apple.SE?

Comment: @Soumya: I voted to move it to superuser.com -- this is more of a general router config question, rather than something specific to a mac.

Comment: @Jim I thought the OP was asking for directions on how to configure the IP on a Snow Leopard machine. Either way, it should not be here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the router config with the MAC (ethernet hardware) address of the
new machine?  Otherwise it will probably give you an address out of its dynamic
pool.

You should be able to disable DHCP and self-assign an appropriate static IP address to 
your Mac. If it doesn't work, that also sounds like a router issue.  Are you using 
the same static IP address previously assigned to the other server?  That might be 
the problem,  if the router thinks that IP address is locked to the old machine's MAC 
address.  If you're using a different IP address, you'll have to change the router config
so it knows how to route the traffic from the public side to the private side of your
LAN.

Comment: Yes, I am, since that is the address that I have the router forwarding to the ports towards.  I erased the previous entry in my router's DHCP table and tried to tie it to the MAC address of the new machine, but the Mac would just keep getting a different IP address.